# Create NSDate with number that from java

Tags: java, ios

I have a number from java "new Date().getTime()", how to create NSDate with it?

java

```
Date d = new Date();
d.setTime(1423460832000L);
System.out.println(DateFormatUtils.format(d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

ios

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1423460832000];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

This code log "47077-09-05 02:40:00 +0000" in ios, but java log "2015-02-09 13:47:12"

Comment: @RealSkeptic Divide by 1000 day is right but time not. "2015-02-09 05:47:12 +0000"

Comment: That's a time zone issue, you can see that the minutes are correct.